# problem "the file exists" with TBB assembly after reuploading

Tags: 2011, templating

during development of a tridion TBB, i stumbled upon a weird error.
I uploaded a new version of my TBB dll, and tried to preview one of my pages to check the result, and i got this error

```
XmlResponder failed render request : 
        <tcmapi:Message version="6.0" from="Anguilla" xmlns:tcmapi="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0/TCMAPI">
  <tcmapi:Response ID="65093962-14d3-4c81-ac4b-b74fe4b9582f" success="false" xmlns:tcmapi="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0/TCMAPI">
    <tcmapi:Error>
      <tcm:Error ErrorCode="80040000" Category="18" Source="mscorlib" Severity="1" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
        <tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040000" Cause="false" MessageID="16138"><![CDATA[Unable to get rendered content of Page (tcm:11-23220-64).]]></tcm:Line>
        <tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040000" Cause="true">
          <![CDATA[The file exists.
 ]]>
        </tcm:Line>
        <tcm:Details>
          <tcm:CallStack>
            <tcm:Location>System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32,String)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>System.IO.Path.InternalGetTempFileName(Boolean)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.CompileAssembly(String)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.Transform(Engine,Template,Package)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template,Package)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package,TemplateInvocation,Template)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine,Template,Package)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template,Package)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package,TemplateInvocation,Template)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine,Template,Package)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template,Package)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package,TemplateInvocation,Template)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformPackage(Template,Package)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformItem(Template,IdentifiableObject)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.TemplatingRenderer.Render(ResolvedItem,PublishInstruction,PublicationTarget,RenderedItem,RenderContext)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderEngine.Render(ResolvedItem,PublishInstruction,PublicationTarget,RenderContext)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderEngine.Render(IdentifiableObject,Template,PublishInstruction,PublicationTarget,RenderContext)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.ComWrapper.RenderEngineFacade.RenderItemWithTemplate(IdentifiableObject,Template,PublishInstruction,PublicationTarget,RenderContext)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.ComWrapper.RenderEngineFacade.RenderItemWithTemplate(IdentifiableObject,Template,String)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.ComWrapper.RenderEngineFacade.RenderPage(UserContext,String,String,String)</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>UtilitiesPublish.RenderPage</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Page.Render</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>Request.Render</tcm:Location>
          </tcm:CallStack>
        </tcm:Details>
      </tcm:Error>
    </tcmapi:Error>
  </tcmapi:Response>
</tcmapi:Message>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some investigation, it turns out there is nothing wrong with my code, but the problem comes from windows.
In the callstack we can see there is a call to the function

```
System.IO.Path.InternalGetTempFileName(Boolean)
```

This function takes care of creating a unique temp file in the c:\windows\temp directory.
After inspection of this directory on my CM (development) server, I noted that this folder contained about 240000 temp files.
After moving these temp files (i didn't want to delete them), the error no longer appeared.

So, i should set a rule to periodically clean up this temp folder. I'm wondering why tridion wouldn't clean up these files

Comment: That is indeed unusual - I don't have that on my servers. Maybe they're left behind because the process crashed somehow and didn't clean it as expected? Maybe as result of debugging efforts?

Comment: 240K temp files? Yikes, that's a lot. Since you found the answer to your own question, can you accept it (by clicking the check mark to its left)?

Comment: Hi Harald - with regards the temp files - do these appear to have been created recently, in a batch/time frame?

Comment: Same issue with us, we could not upload new files, finish workflows, or even preview. Our fix was not only the Temp drive for upload but the AppData > Local > Temp for the "MTS User" needed to be cleaned up as well.
`C:\Users\[MTSUser]\AppData\Local\Temp`

Answer (score 1):

After doing some google search, I came to know that

> **The Temp directory having more than 65,353 folders, will start causing this issue.**

As **@Harald** said, it requires periodical clean up.